# Show Activity on Lock Screen java Android

Tags: java, android, notifications

I need to implement a sort of call functionality with the help of Firebase notification but the problem is the screen that is visible on the notification received is not showing if the screen is locked can anyone give any tips about that?
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Just done that by using Power Manager

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity
        android:name=".IncomingCall"
        android:exported="false"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:showOnLockScreen="true"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" />
```

**Activity from where to shift**

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "myalarmapp:alarm.");
    wl.acquire(5000);

    Intent startAlarmActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), IncomingCall.class);
    startAlarmActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startAlarmActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startAlarmActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(startAlarmActivity);

    wl.release();
```

**Destination Activity**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {

        setShowWhenLocked(true);
        setTurnScreenOn(true);
        KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        keyguardManager.requestDismissKeyguard(this, null);
    } else {
        final Window win = getWindow();
        win.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
        win.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON);
    }
```